# C# Selecting same index on multiple listBox

Tags: c#, events, select, listbox

Okay, so I have four listBox controls. I want to select the same index on all four listBox when one item is clicked on any of them. To be mentioned, I do change the index sometimes in the program. I tryed using a method listSelectChange (int index) and adding for each listBox an event for selectIndexChange, but it would activate the event even if the select is made by the program and not by user-control.

Please don't use classes, just a brute method would be fine!

Comment: You can unsubscribe from `selectedIndexChanged` before you update the `ListBox` and re-subscribe to it immediately after that. It's a common practice.

Comment: Please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unsubscribe from selectedIndexChanged before you update the ListBox and re-subscribe to it immediately after that. It's a common practice.

Since you gave no code example I'm doing some guessing here.

```
// Enumerable of all the synchronized list boxes
IEnumerable<ListBox> mListBoxes = ...
...
public void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var currentListBox = (ListBox)sender;

    // Do this for every listbox that isn't the one that was just updated
    foreach(var listBox in mListBoxes.Where(lb => lb != currentListBox)) {
        listBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= OnSelectedIndexChanged;
        listBox.SelectedIndex = currentListBox.SelectedIndex;
        listBox.SelectedIndexChanged += OnSelectedIndexChanged;
    }
}
```